# The file name must only contain ASCII 32-126 characters except some special character

Tags: javascript, regex, ascii

I have a file and I require some Regex validation on that.

The validation is the file name must only contain ASCII 32-126 characters,
except:`–34 ["] –39 [’] –59 [;] –60 [<] –61 [=] –62 [>] –92 [\]`

Additionally, the file name cannot include the following sequence of characters: –%00

```
let filename = "filename"
let regex = ""
console.log(filename);
```

could someone take a look and let me know the solution?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following Regex expression:

```
^(?:(?!["';<=>\\])[\x20-\x7E])+$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Q67C3/2)

Explanation:

```
^                  # start of line
(?:                # non-capturing group
   (?!["';<=>\\])  # negative lookahead - do not to match if contains given symbols
   [\x20-\x7E]     # match in range from ASCII 32-126
)                  # close non-capturing group
+                  # match 1-unlimited times
$                  # end of line
```